# how to get only those which have maximum value in a specified column in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a table with "customer_id, date, installment_no, amount" columns. I want to get the information of last installment of each customer_id till today. here installment_no is int type and when a new installment is deposited, the installment_no is increased by 1 in new entry. My table look like:

```
CS1001 | 12-06-2013 | 1 | 2500
CS1002 | 19-06-2013 | 1 | 1600
CS1001 | 14-07-2013 | 2 | 2500
```

I want to get a sqlcommand statement for do so.

Comment: Please, always provide what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Group all records by customer_id, then order all customer's records by installment_no, and select only record with max installment_no from each group:

```
from c in customers
group c by c.customer_id into g
select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.installment_no).First()
```

Same with pure SQL if you don't use Linq

```
SELECT c.* FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT customer_id, MAX(installment_no) max_installment
   FROM Customers
   GROUP BY customer_id
) cmax
ON c.customer_id = cmax.customer_id
   AND c.installment_no = cmax.max_installment
```

Comment: sorry sir, to late response. I'm new and use other way to sqlcommand statement. what correction should i make in my sqlcommand statement to meet your sql statement or through which way can I use your statement, I use this way.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  customer_id,date,max(installment_no),amount from cutomer", connectionsql);

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.customer_id)
                 .Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(y=>y.installment_no).First())
                 .ToList();
```